# Full-width color behind line in word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Microsoft Word themes have styles like this:

[image]

With color behind a line of text that spans the width of the page.

How do I do this myself with custom colours?

Answer (score 22):

In Office 365:

1. Put the cursor on the line/paragraph you want to change. *Note: Do not highlight or select text, just put the cursor there with no text selected.*
2. Click "Design" tab.
3. Click "Page Borders" (far right), which opens the "Borders and Shading" options dialog(*).
4. Click the shading tab and use the "Fill" drop-box to change the
   colour of the border which will be full width of the page.

You can also use this on a text selection to change just the selected text (not full width).

(*) Why Microsoft think naming this "Page Borders" on the ribbon and then "Borders and Shading" in the dialog is beyond me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was somewhere... but could not fathom it was under "Page Borders"! ‍♂️ I think it was under paragraph in earlier versions.

Comment: I had difficulty changing the formatting for an existing TOC, but was able to get it eventually by turning on the Paragraph Marks, highlighting the mark, and then doing the above.

Answer (score 6):

Use the "shading" dialogue to set a shading for the paragraph in question:

Menu --> Borders --> Borders and Shading --> Shading

Here, select a colour, and pay attention that the "Apply to" field is set to "Paragraph".

[image]

(This is for MS Word 2010, but I suppose it has not changed in later versions; it was the same also in earlier ones.)

Answer (score 0):

@Gavin Thornton answer is very good. But if you need more styling like padding around the text then you need to use table. Create a table with only 1 cell and then format the cell according to your need. The process is below-

### Insert table:

Go to **Insert** -> **Table** -> Select only 1 cell

### Remove Border:

Go to **Table Design** -> **Borders** -> **No Border**

### Add Background Shedding:

Select the table cell -> Got to **Table Design** -> **Shedding** -> Select color

### Add Padding:

Select the table cell -> Go to **Home** -> On the paragraph section go to **Line Spacing** -> **Line Spacing Options** -> Now you can add **Indentaion** (Left / Right) or **Spacing** (Top / Bottom)

Finally you will get a cool heading design. Sample is attached here.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in increasing the height of the shaded area without creating a table, add a border around the shaded area. The thickness of the line can be adjusted to adjust the height of the box. Just use the Design tab, Page Borders option, and Borders tab. Make sure to color the border in the same color as the shading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).