# Full-width color behind line in Word within list?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, text-formatting

I'm trying to achieve something similar to
[Full-width color behind line in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1288483/full-width-color-behind-line-in-word):
I want a background color until the end of the line, but then within a bullet list and not as a separate paragraph.

The following screenshot displays the issue:

[image: No shading at bullet list]

What I want to achieve, is that the shading in the bullet list will be the same as the shading shown above the bullet list: I want it shaded until the end of the line. The shading setting of the style is already on "paragraph" and not on "text", however, Word still only shades the text only and not the paragraph.

Is there a way to obtain full paragraph shading in a bullet list?

Answer (score 1):

The words of your question are not enough for me to see into your mind. 
If I’ve misunderstood, please forgive me and clarify your question.

If you want to have a single style that works one way in a bullet
and another way elsewhere,
I believe that you’re out of luck
(unless you want to do something with VBA, which strikes me as hacky).

But, if you’re simply trying to format the text the two ways:

Always use the “Borders and Shading…” dialog box, “Shading” tab.

[image: the GUI]

For the “all the way to the end of the line” style, choose Apply to: Paragraph. 
For the “not all the way to the end of the line” style, choose Apply to: Text.

[image: the result]

Comment: Thank you Scott, I have clarified my question. The settings you show are already applied to the "Source Code" style, however, Word still does not shade it until the end of the line (what I want it to do) when the style is applied to within a bullet list.